# Stored procedure with ROW instead of a list of parameters

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, insert

I have a table with 15 columns, and trying to create a stored procedure in PL SQL that will only insert a row in a table using the `INSERT` statement.

I would like to know if it is possible to declare the list of IN parameters of the stored procedure as a `RECORD` structure instead of 15 parameter, so when calling this stored procedure, I will only pass a `RECORD` structure instead of 15 single variables.

Is that possible in PL SQL? If no, is there any shorthand for doing this kind of declarations? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  You can even use the predefined `%rowtype` record.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_row( p_rec IN table_name%rowtype )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_name
    VALUES p_rec;
END;
```

Comment: thanks That's great, calling it i suppose would e as simple as referencing the rec.field := value ? and passing the rec to the stored proc? is that correct

Comment: @joe - Assuming that the caller also defines `rec` as `table_name%rowtype`, then yes.